# How to convert unknown/mixed encoding file to UTF-8

Tags: php, text, encoding, utf-8

I am using retrieving an XML file from a remote service which is *supposed* to be UTF-8, as the header is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.  However, certain parts of it is apparently not UTF-8, as when I load it into PHP's XMLReader extension, it throws some sort of "Not UTF-8 as expected" error when parsing over certain parts of the document (parts that look like they have been copy-pasted directly from MS Word).

I am looking for ideas to solve this error.  Is there some program I can use to "fix" the file of any non-uft8 encodings?  A PHP solution or any other solution will do

Answer (score 0):

Depending on  what encoding it is you are converting *from*,  quick and easy utf-8 safe strings,`utf8_encode` function is your friend, but *only for iso8859-1 encoding*. Also, your txt cannot be already UTF-8 else you have good chances of having garbled text.

See the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) for more info:

```
// Usage can be as simple as this.
$name = utf8_encode($contact['name']);
```

On the other hand, if you need to convert from any other encoding, you will have to maybe look into  [incov() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Good-luck